# Python Pandas countifs with unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m having a dataset with entries where one column is an identifier, let’s say column A. I’d like to count how many entries in column A which is unique and where column B is between x and y and column C is equal with z.

To examplify:

| Row | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1001 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1001 | 6 | 1 |
| 4 | 1001 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1002 | 7 | 0 |
| 6 | 1002 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 1002 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | 1002 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | 1003 | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | 1003 | 3 | 0 |
| 11 | 1003 | 3 | 1 |
| 12 | 1003 | 4 | 1 |

What I want to achieve is following:
Count how many unique values of column A which has exactly two entries in column B between 2-4 and where column C is equal to 1.

Looking at the table this would return 1 since only Column A=1002 meets all criteria  (row 7 and 8).

I've tried some code but I don't know how to succeed with the unique value criteria in column A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. First I subset on your conditions, then I count the the number of occurrences, check if it is 2, and then sum those.

```
sum(df[(df['Column B ']> 1) & (df['Column B ']<4) & (df['Column C'] == 1)]['Column A '].value_counts() == 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

first create a condition to filter your dataframe

```
con = df['Column B'].between(2,4) & df['Column C'].eq(1)
```

then use a `groupby` operation.

```
df.loc[con].groupby('Column A')['Column A'].nunique()

Column A
1001    1
1002    1
1003    1
Name: Column A, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df.loc[con]

    Row  Column A  Column B  Column C
0     1      1001         4         1
3     4      1001         4         1
6     7      1002         2         1
7     8      1002         3         1
10   11      1003         3         1
11   12      1003         4         1
```